# Not terminated set of [] in regex (C#)

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to parse a text looking for data inside this pattern:

```
{{([^]+)}}
```

i.e. any sequence of characters between `{{` and `}}` .
But, when I try to build a `Regex` object:

```
Regex _regex = new Regex("{{([^]+)}}", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

I got this error:

```
analysis of "{{([^]+)}}" - Set of [] not terminated....
```

whatever it means... 
Someone has an hint?

Comment: `[^]` doesn't make sense.

Comment: regxr understand it...

Comment: `^` means exclude, so there are no characters in your group.

Comment: yes exclude any elements in a void group... i.e. include everything... what's a way to create a group that accepts any sequence?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for `.`.

Comment: `Regex _regex = new Regex("{{(.+)}}", RegexOptions.Singleline);`. ECMAScript `[^]` = `(?s:.)` in .NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of `[^...]` is to negate character classes present in the specified list. After the `^` symbol, in order to define a correct regular expression, you should include a set of characters to exclude like, for example `[^a]+` (this matches one or more characters that don't include the literal `a`).

The regex you are attempting to define is probably:

```
{{\s*([\w]+)\s*}}
```

Visit [this link](https://regex101.com/r/Ra61Ir/4) for trying a working demo.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `[^]` is not a valid regex, because you need to specify at least one symbol that you wish to exclude.

In order to capture the string up to the closing `}}` change the expression to this:

```
{{((?:[^}]|}[^}])*)}}
```

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/puMjK9/1)